# Breakpoints are not hit when debugging Node JS app in VS Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I don't know if I am missing something but I can't manage to debug this very simple Node JS program with VS Code (I'm on a Ubuntu env) :

[image: Code]

When I start debugging, my breakpoint is "set but not yet bound". The strange thing is that the execution will stop on exceptions if I ask it to, but it will NEVER stop on my breakpoints.

My launch.json file is as follows :

[image: launch.json]

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround. There is a bug on breakpoints in VS Code and to get it work :

1. Write an exception on your code at the beginning
2. Debug your app. It should stop on the exception
3. While it is stopped on the exception, set your breakpoints
4. Remove the exception code
5. The next time you debug, breakpoints should be hit !

Comment: This worked for me when trying to debug an Alexa skill.